# BotFramework-WebChat - dynamically change language

Tags: angular, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using BotFramework-WebChat in multilingual site, where I want to set bot locale on language change which I select from dropdown, can any one guide me for implementing this.

Even after passing changes local it stays with initial set locale, I am using it in Angular 4.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    BotChat.App({
      directLine: {
        secret: '',
        webSocket: false
      },
      user: {
        id: 'userid',
        name: 'me',
      },
      bot: {
        id: 'botid',
        name: 'bot'
      },
      resize: 'detect',
      formatOptions:
      {
      showHeader: true
      },
      locale: this.translate.currentLang
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    console.log(this.translate.currentLang)

  }
```

Language change is working fine for site but how to change language of chat control?

Comment: you should use backchannel functionality to send the information to your bot when the language is changed by the user with the dropdown

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `lang` attribute in your top-level HTML tag: `<html lang="es">`.

Or use the HTML `meta` tag to define your WebChat client's intended audience language.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language

Next add your localized content strings to the WebChat [src/Strings.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/v3/src/Strings.ts) file scoped to your locale code, as described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3#strings

Finally, build and deploy your customized WebChat instance as described in this section: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3#building-web-chat

Comment: Note that this solution applies to Web Chat v3. I have modified the links accordingly, as the master branch is v4.